# Child of element on top of other element

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have an interesting `Z-INDEX` problem.

Here is my HTML structure.

```
<div class="player">
<div class="player-line">
    <div class="player-handle"></div>
    <!-- /.player-handle -->
</div>
<!-- /.player-line -->
<div class="branch"></div>
<!-- /.branch -->
```

Now my element .branch  MUST be OVER .player-line, but NEVER over .player-handle. Is this possible?
Here is my [JSFiddle experiment.](http://jsfiddle.net/t22EW/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `z-index` from `.player-line` and set an higher z-index to `.player-handle`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/t22EW/5/

(tested on Firefox and Chrome)
Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not so long as your player-handle is a child of the object that you want branch to be above. You're going to need all three to be at the same DOM level with different z-index values.

Answer (score 0):

do you want like this. give the high z-index value to `.player-line`
[image]

```
.player-line {
        position: absolute;
        width: 370px;
        height: 100%;
        background: #4B93E6;
    z-index: 102;}
```

check the Fiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/t22EW/8/